# How to get "MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN" programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I have a .net 6 main service that depending on need hosts other services and consume its services.

- Service hosting done by calling "service1.exe" using `System.Diagnostics.Process`.
- This shows a console with some message including a message "http://[::]:59504" here the port number will be changing every time a new instance is started.
- This message is programmatically read using `StandardOutput` of the instance of `System.Diagnostics.Process` and stored as <service1_url>
- An Http client is created to send the request

```
Client = new HttpClient();
Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(service1_url);
HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.PostAsJsonAsync($"/api/AwesomeJob1", fileName).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This works fine in IIS Express, but gives an error in IIS as "'MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN' does not match the expected pairing token..." found in log.

How to get the pairing token programmatically from the host?

Let me know if I need to share any additional information?

Comment: So you have a web server starting another web server? Which sounds like something you really shouldn't be doing.... You'll have to be careful about which environment variables you pass through to the child process.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman: Yes, another web server is being started by my web server. This will serve as a temporary solution while I look for a more effective run-time service discovery method.

Comment: When hosting in IIS, IIS passes custom headers to the asp.net application which will be missing when hiting the asp.net core process directly. When using IIS to reverse proxy asp.net core, you should only access it via IIS.